# "Sollte.., dann müsste..." -- necessarily counter-factual?

Tags: translation

Or could it, also, mean (in some contexts, at least) "Should A be this, B would be that" (which is called "future less vivid conditional" in Ancient Greek). I'm asking this because the two published English translations of a sentence that interests me, which begins with

> Sollte die Ewigkeit etwas anderes sein als das leere Immersein,...

render it as "If eternity were something other than...", i.e., as counter-factual. I'm wondering whether this is the only possible interpretation.

The quote is from Heideggers talk *Begriff der Zeit*, see [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=1TP1AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA151&ots=5J83lmqCWp&dq=Sollte%20die%20Ewigkeit%20etwas%20anderes%20sein%20als%20das%20leere%20Immersein&hl=de&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q=Sollte%20die%20Ewigkeit%20etwas%20anderes%20sein%20als%20das%20leere%20Immersein&f=false).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Call me oldschool - is the headline part of the question body? Please consider repeating it - for me the headline is the summarized topic and I read the question body at once without the headline. This is mainly as I struggle a bit to get your context, example and question separated.

Comment: Side note: For a clear counter-factual, I'd have said "*Wäre* die Ewigkeit ..."

Answer (score 8):

It's not necessarily counter-factual. *Sollte* may also introduce a hypothesis.

> Sollte er schon daheim sein, dann müsste er auch deinen Brief schon gelesen haben.

Comment: While this answers the title question, it is not helpful for the given quote, where eternity is unlikely to change its nature while we are waiting - so the deficiency of the question carries over to this answer.

Comment: @guidot We will never know about the nature of eternity. This answer is exactly, what OP was asking about: hypothesis.